# Serialize inputs and select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  need to serialize inputs and selected option in table  row(tr)

```
<form action='' METHOD='post' id='formConfirmOrder'>
<table id='viewTableOrders'>
<tr id='vagon1'>
  <td>
   <select name="order[1][rail_path]" title="1">
     <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="1">Patch1</option><option value="2">Patch2</option>
     <option value="3" selected="selected">Patch3</option><option value="5">Patch4</option></select>
  </td>
 <td>
<input name="order[1][vagon_id]" value="210" type="hidden"/>
</td>
```

```
    $('#formConfirmOrder > #viewTableOrders tr#vagon1 
                                            select option:selected,
       #formConfirmOrder > #viewTableOrders tr#vagon1 input').serializeArray();
```

..
**FireBug**Only inputs

```
[Object { name="order[1][vagon_id]", more...}]
```

I can`t get selected value from option!
Inputs were serialized. ,but not options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to serialize the `<select>` not the options...it'll grab the selected `<option>` elements [automatically](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/ajax.js#L101) (by getting the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) of the `<select>`, which is an array here), like this:

```
$('#formConfirmOrder > #viewTableOrders tr#vagon1 select,
   #formConfirmOrder > #viewTableOrders tr#vagon1 input').serializeArray();
```

Or, if you want all inputs, just use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector, like this:

```
$('#vagon1 :input').serializeArray();
```

Since `id` attributes *should* be unique, this should work, given valid markup...if your IDs aren't unique, that's another issue you need to address.

Comment: Thank you!I just added tr#vagon1 select (not select option:selected)

Comment: @Dezigo - if our markup is valid there's need for that long selector, it's actually tremendously less efficient, just use the last ID :)